# Program Throwing a java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I have written the program below for a class.  It is supposed to read and validate user input (2 numbers and a char), repeating until valid input is provided. Then it must print out a checkerboard pattern of the given dimensions, using the specified `char`.  When I submit the program to the required automated testing service, it scores only 93.3%.  I can’t figure out what the error report is trying to tell me. Here’s my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of rows, columns, and fill character: ");
        // userInput = sc.nextLine();

        String[] gridArray = new String[3]; // split by spaces

        gridArray[0] = sc.next();
        gridArray[1] = sc.next();
        gridArray[2] = sc.next();

        gridArray[0].trim();
        gridArray[1].trim();
        gridArray[2].trim();

        int row, column;
        row = Integer.parseInt(gridArray[0]);
        column = Integer.parseInt(gridArray[1]);

        if (row <= 0 || column <= 0 || gridArray[2].length() >= 2) {
            while (row <= 0 || column <= 0 || gridArray[2].length() >= 2) {
                System.out.println("Enter the number of rows, columns, and fill character: ");

                gridArray[0] = sc.next();
                gridArray[1] = sc.next();
                gridArray[2] = sc.next();

                gridArray[0].trim();
                gridArray[1].trim();
                gridArray[2].trim();

                row = Integer.parseInt(gridArray[0]);
                column = Integer.parseInt(gridArray[1]);

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Solid:");

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                System.out.print(gridArray[2]);
                if (j == column - 1) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Checkerboard:");

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < column; y++) {
                if (x % 2 == 1) {
                    if (y % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(gridArray[2]);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (y % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.print(gridArray[2]);
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
                if (y == column - 1) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the error:

Solid (word above the error)

```
symptom: java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
at csc212hw04.Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

The testing service is WEB-CAT if that helps.

Comment: maybe check your whitespace.

Comment: I just checked, there doesn’t seem to be any problem with it.

Comment: In Java, String objects are immutable—that is, they can never be changed.  The trim() method, like all methods, does not alter a String's contents;  it returns a *new* String object with leading and trailing whitespace removed.  Your code is ignoring that returned object, which makes your call to `trim()` the same as doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you describe can happen when the scanner cannot find more data.
The error message tells you that this happened on line 31:

> ```
> gridArray[2] = sc.next();
> ```

Check the input data, or your algorithm,
as you are trying to read more data than available.

For example,
this primitive snippet gives identical stack trace,
for trying to read past the end of the input data:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1 2");
scanner.next();
scanner.next();
scanner.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that "Solid" is the name of the test case.

The exception is telling you that in the course of executing `Scanner.next()`, it turned out that there was no more input available (the end of the input stream had been reached).  The method invocation in question appears on line 31 of file `Main.java`, which, if I've counted correctly is this:

```
                gridArray[2] = sc.next();
```

(the first appearance).  Either the input presented by the judge is malformed, in which case the judge apparently expects the program to handle the problem differently, or your program is somehow parsing it incorrectly.

I think it more likely that you are parsing incorrectly, but either way, read the problem specifications very carefully.  In particular, pay attention to distinctions such as between "separated by spaces" and "separated by [exactly] one space".  Also take note of all the details of what inputs are valid.

Based in part on the name of the failing test case, I *speculate* that perhaps the input provides a space character as the fill character.  That is possible if the second dimension is supposed to be separated from the fill character by a fixed number of spaces (e.g. one).  In that event, you may need a different approach than a `Scanner` for reading the input.

Answer (score 0):

The testing service may be giving you a test case with less than the expected number of input values. Look into the Scanner API's hasNext() method for inspiration.